# Convert String to Hash after submitting to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am fighting with importing hashes from database and using them inside my code.

i am sending hash into database. I have text column with an array:true option in my database.
My response from database from this field looks like:

```
["{:name=>\"na życie2\", :planned=>2000, :budget_group=>\"Zdrowie\"}", "{:name=>\"pies\", :planned=>400, :budget_group=>\"Zdrowie\"}"]
```

Now i want to receive the data from this column and use it in format like this:

```
hash[:name]
```

This is what i've got:

```
budget_plan = Budget.last.budget_plan
budget_plan.each do |i|
  item = eval(i)
  puts item[:name]
end
```

It works but i am afraid, it is not safe.
Do you know maybe some better solution?

I was trying some solutions from other StackOverflow topics, but only eval seems actual and well working (still not safe)

Comment: The better alternative is almost always to actually create a separate table to house the data as the lets you normalize the data and query it properly. If its a special case scenario where the data does not adhere to any sort of schema you can use a JSON type column but that should really be a last resort.

Comment: @max, in this example are only 2 hashes in array, but i want to use 50 hashes per array. It is possible that there will be added 50000 hashes in 1000 arrays per month. After 12 months it will be 6 million of hashes. In this case is it still better to create table with 6 million records than table with 12k records with array of hashes?

Comment: If you want to to be able to query the data - yes absolutely. You're sorely mistaken if you think that there are any performance benefits to the approach you are currently on.

Comment: Multiple values per column is [a known anti-pattern](https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/03/database-modelization-anti-patterns/) and storing a serialized ruby hash JSON or comes with its own overhead in terms of serialization/de-serialization and its not really going to take less space just because you completely bungle the relational model. Add to the the fact that you can't really use the data in meaningful way in the database or index it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @max, your comments are actually the answer for this topic, if you move it to the answers, i would love to mark it as resolution. I will change my whole structure and save data inside new table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just don't do it** - its a horrible design decision. There almost no good reasons to not create a separate table and storing serialized strings is something which just should NOT be done in 2020.

This is what you are giving up:

- Data normalization
- Referential integrity
- ActiveRecord::Assocations
- Being able to query the data!
- Having a model that encapsulates the data
- Actually being able to maintain and scale the application

---

```
class Budget < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plans
  belongs_to :budget_group
end

# rails g model plan budget:belongs_to name planned:integer 
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :budget
  has_one :budget_group, through: :budget
end

class BudgetGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :budgets
  has_many :plans, through: :budgets
end
```

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord's [serialize method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) can take care of that automatically.

Just define the field in your model like this:

```
serialize :budget_plan, Array
```

and you are ready to go. Save an array, get out an array.

```
budget_plan = Budget.last.budget_plan
budget_plan.each { |i| puts i[:name] }
```

If you use this method, you should redefine your db field not to use `array: true`. Instead, use a text field.

Comment: your answer sounds clean and nice to implement, but i am using an array of many hashes (as you can see in my question). I guess, i should change my structure from array of hashes to hash nested tree then? Do you have an idea how my hash looks like then?

Comment: Yes, you might 1) change your data from an array to a hash of hashes. Or 2) define your field as `serialize :budget_plan, Array`, and then save an array of hashes. This should NOT be combined with your setting `array: true` for the database. Instead, use a text or longtext field in the database. 3) If you want to use a Postgres-specific technique instead of `serialize`, use a json or jsonb field type, as advised [here](https://www.netguru.com/codestories/postgres-arrays-vs-json-datatypes-in-rails-5).